# how to print JQuery mobile tap event data dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

In the code the tap event is being triggered but the `array[i]` is printed `null`.
If I click any index it prints `" "`. Why is that printing `null` instead of clicked value?

Please suggest the Solution For It... Its not even Printing `array[last index]`... It Just Prints `null or " "`

This is my code:

```
function abc() {
    var array = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"];
    var innerHTML = "";



    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        innerHTML += "<div id = \"MyID_"+i+" \"></div>" ;
    }

    var xyz = document.getElementById("OuterHTML");
    xyz.innerHTML = innerHTML;



    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

       var tempID = "#MyID_"+i;

        $(tempID).on("tap", function(album){
            console.log(array[i]);          
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: Because that is not an `array`! it's an `object`!

Comment: You're defining an object, not an array. Use this: `var array = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"]` Note `[]`, not `{}`

Comment: @DhavalMarthak and Rory McCrossan, Please See Edited question

Comment: Events handlers are asynchronous. `i` will always be `10` by the time `console.log(array[i])` runs.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi   suggest me solution Please

Comment: @Group, technically I would use a closure, but I am not able to suggest something reliable with your current code -- I don't know where `id` comes from, and it looks like you're registering ten `tap` handlers on the same element or set of elements, which I don't understand.

Comment: @Group, I would use event delegation instead of adding event listener on every `div`

Comment: @Venugopal Please give an answer bro...

Comment: @Group in my answer below, i made a fiddle with `click` event instead of `tap`. hope that helps too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using closure, you can do like

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   var tempID = "#MyID_"+i;
    (function(x){
        $(tempID).on("click", function(album){
            console.log(array[x]);          
        });
    }(i));
}
```

using event delegation

```
$('#OuterHTML').on('click', function (e) {
    console.log(array[$(e.target).index()]);
});
```

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4zeq1m00/)

Comment: awesome Venu... That worked for me... Thank you very much